# NetworkD3 Sankey diagram in R: How to calculate value for each link?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, dplyr, networkd3

I am attempting to follow the example of the R port of d3Network to create a Sankey Plot as elaborated (as stated here: https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/). I load the following sample "Energy" dataset:

```
    # Load energy projection data

    URL <- paste0("https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/",
    "master/JSONdata/energy.json")

    Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
```

Importing the "Energy" dataset generates two new data.frames; nodes and links. Taking a look at the links data reveals the following format:

```
    head(Energy$links)
      source target   value
  1        0      1 124.729
  2        1      2   0.597
  3        1      3  26.862
  4        1      4 280.322
  5        1      5  81.144
  6        6      2  35.000
```

The "source" column indicates the node of origin, the "target" column indicates the destination node, while the "value" column indicates the value of each individual link.

Even though this is fairly simple conceptually, I am having tremendous difficulties getting a dataset that I am working with in the same format as the `Energy$links` data.frame. I have been able to get my data in the following format, but am drawing a complete blank on how I could transform it further:

```
   head(sampleSankeyData, n = 10L)
    clientID                node1
      <int>                <chr>
 1     23969 1 Community Services
 2     39199      1 Youth Justice
 3     23595      1 Mental Health
 4     15867 1 Community Services
 5     18295            3 Housing
 6     18295            2 Housing
 7     18295 1 Community Services
 8     18295            4 Housing
 9     15253            1 Housing
 10    27839 1 Community Services
```

What I want to be able to do is to aggregate the number of unique clients for each link. For example, in the above sub-set of data, due to client 18295, the link for "1 Community Services" to "2 Housing" should have a value of one (as should the links for "2 Housing" to "3 Housing" as well as "3 Housing" to "4 Housing"). As such, I want to be able to get the data in the same format as `Energy$links` in the Sankey diagram example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df <- tribble(
~number, ~clientID,         ~node1,
1 ,    23969, '1 Community Services',
2 ,    39199,      '1 Youth Justice',
3 ,    23595,      '1 Mental Health',
4 ,    15867, '1 Community Services',
5 ,    18295,            '3 Housing',
6 ,    18295,            '2 Housing',
7 ,    18295, '1 Community Services',
8 ,    18295,            '4 Housing',
9 ,    15253,            '1 Housing',
10,    27839, '1 Community Services')

df2 <- mutate(df, step=as.numeric(str_sub(node1, end=1))) %>%
  spread(step, node1, sep='_') %>%
  group_by(clientID) %>%
  summarise(step1 = sort(unique(step_1))[1],
            step2 = sort(unique(step_2))[1],
            step3 = sort(unique(step_3))[1],
            step4 = sort(unique(step_4))[1])

df3 <- bind_rows(select(df2,1,source=2,target=3),
            select(df2,1,source=3,target=4),
            select(df2,1,source=4,target=5)) %>%
  group_by(source, target) %>%
  summarise(clients=n())
```

and to use that with `networkD3`...

```
links <- df3 %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% # ungroup just to be safe
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(source) & !is.na(target)) # remove lines without a link

# build the nodes data frame based on nodes in your links data frame
nodeFactors <- factor(sort(unique(c(links$source, links$target))))
nodes <- data.frame(name = nodeFactors)

# convert the source and target values to the index of the matching node in the 
# nodes data frame
links$source <- match(links$source, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1
links$target <- match(links$target, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1

# plot
library(networkD3)
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'source', 
              Target = 'target', Value = 'clients', NodeID = 'name')
```